# react get values from {"B8":"C6"}

Tags: reactjs

Trying to get values from {"B8":"C6"}

not sure if it is an array or object

```
            let move = theGame.aiMove(3)

            alert("this is move " + JSON.stringify(move) )
```

//alerts: this is move {"G8":"F6"}

I would like to get

var from = G8

var to = F6

I have tried

```
var from = move[1]
```

which just ends up as undefined

Comment: {"B8":"C6"} how come you are getting {"G8":"F6"}

Answer (score 0):

you're turning a json into a string... if you want the content you can print move.G8 directly and as a result you will have "F6"

```
let move = theGame.aiMove(3) // {"B8":"C6"}
alert("this is move " + move.G8 )
var from = move.G8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.entries()`

```js
var val = {"B8":"C6"}
var valArr = Object.entries(val)[0];
var from = valArr[0]
var to = valArr[1]
console.log("from: ",from,"to: ",to)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an array you can try this with object

```
let data={"G8":"F6"}
var from;
var to;
Object.keys(data).forEach((item)=>{
        from = item;
        to = data[item];
})
console.log(from,to)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect just one pair, you also can do it this way:

```
const move = theGame.aiMove(3); // {"B8":"C6"}

const [from] = Object.keys(move);
const to = move[from];

console.log("from: ", from, " to: ", to);
```